# CanCan: Load and Authorize some resources in a Controllers without models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, cancan, cancancan

I've a controller without model. In this controller we are loading some other resources. Most importantly the application has multi-tenancy feature.

Here is the code:

```
# ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.owner?
      can :manage, Tool, tenant_id: user.tenant.id
    end
  end
end

# boxes_controller.rb
class BoxesController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource class: false

  def index
    tools = Tool.all
  end
end
```

### What is the problem?:

Say, `user1` of `tenant1` creates `tool1` and the `user2` of `tenant2` creates `tool2`.

The problem is, from `tenant1`, `user1` can access `tool2`! :(

Did I wrote anything wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if user.owner?
  can :manage, Tool do |tools|
    tools.tenant_id == user.tenant.id
  end
end
```

and in controller

```
authorize_resource class: false
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've tried it and no luck :(, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is really bad habit of mine "not to read documentation of a gem completely". I've found solution here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records

```
# ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.owner?
      can :manage, Tool, tenant_id: user.tenant.id
    end
  end
end

# boxes_controller.rb
class BoxesController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource class: false
  before_action :set_tool, only: %i(edit update destroy)

  def index
    tools = Tool.accessible_by(current_ability)
  end

  private

  def set_tool
    @tool = Tool.find params[:id]
    authorize! :manage, @tool
  end
end
```

Maybe it would help someone. Thanks!